# Code for sending a float down a SPI link

Tags: embedded, spi

I came across a bit of code to send a a float down a SPI link, I'm having a really hard time understanding it.

First point of confusion:
***(uint32_t *)(&f)**

Second point of confusion:
**uint8_t *byte = (uint8_t *)(&dword);**

Third point of confusion:
**for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(uint32_t) ; i++, byte++)**

```
void spi_send_dword(SPI_TypeDef *spi, uint32_t dword) {
  uint8_t *byte = (uint8_t *)(&dword);

  for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(uint32_t) ; i++, byte++)
    spi_transfer_byte(spi, *byte);
} // spi_send_float()

void spi_send_float(SPI_TypeDef *spi, float f) {
  spi_send_dword(spi, *(uint32_t *)(&f));
} // spi_send_float()
```

In addition, if anyone knows a better way to do this I would love to hear it. Can't really find anything around.

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour. Use a `union`. Also note that the code will be very specific for the implementation. If you need to read the data with a different platform, define a proper exchange format, e.g. an ASCII representation.

Answer (score 0):

SPI is a byte oriented serial communications protocol.  Datatypes such as float and uint32_t are made up of multiple bytes.  So how do you send multi-byte variables over a byte oriented serial communications protocol?  One byte at a time, of course.

This code takes the address of the multibyte variable and casts it to pointer to uint8_t.  Then it uses the byte pointer to iterate through all the bytes of the multi-byte variable to send them one at a time.

The general process at work here is called [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).  The receiving end performs deserialization to restore the original multi-byte value.

This specific technique of casting to a uint8_t* and iterating is quite common in my experience.  It's not clear why you're looking for a better way.

Comment: There is no requirement floats and integer types use multiple bytes. They can consist of a single byte as well. If you have octets in mind: Many SPI modules support wider transfers, e.g. 16 bit. There is no standard for SPI; it all depends on the devices.

Answer (score -1):

There's a lot of things wrong with your code.

1)  floats almost certainly aren't 32 bits.

2)  "DWORD" also aren't 32 bits.

3)  There's no guarantee the target you're sending the float to has the same internal representation (byte order, bit order)

But to answer your 'points of confusion', (which are, in reality, just C questions):

First:  take a pointer to the float, cast it to a pointer to a uint32_t, then get the uint32_t value at that address.  This is theoretically just getting the raw bit representation of the floating point number.  It's not going to work right because floats usually aren't 32 bits.

Second:  get a byte pointer to the uint32_t value passed into the array.

Third:  for each byte of a uint32_t, do stuff, increment both the counter and the byte pointer each iteration.

It probably would be much more "correct" to change `void spi_send_float(SPI_TypeDef *spi, float f)` to be:

```
void spi_send_float(SPI_TypeDef *spi, float myfloat) {
  uint8_t *byte = (uint8_t *)(&myfloat);

  for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(float) ; i++, byte++)
    spi_transfer_byte(spi, *byte);
} // spi_send_float()
```

At least this way you're transferring all the bytes of the float regardless of whether it's the same size as a `uint32_t` or not.  You're still stuck with the problem of bit/byte order on the other end of the wire.

Comment: floats and DWORDs have been 32-bits on most projects I have worked on.  What size do you think they should be?

Comment: @kkrambo you are right about the type `float` (but not **floats** in general). However, `DWORD is not a common term. It could mean anything, dependent on platfor. on e.g. ARM it would mean 64 bits (2 words).

Comment: "take a pointer to the float, cast it to a pointer to a uint32_t, then get the uint32_t value" - et voila: undefined behaviour.